# Updating cakephp form input with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp

I'm having a lot of difficulty in updating a cakephp input, based on other inputs within the same cakephp form. Here is the code to form:

```
echo $this->Form->input('UnitPrice',['id'=>'unitPrice', 'type' => 'number']);    
echo $this->Form->input('SalePercent', ['id'=>'salePercent', 'type'=>'number']);
echo $this->Form->input('SalePrice', ['id'=>'salePrice', 'readonly'=>'readonly']);
```

Here is the jscript:

```
$('#salePercent').on('input', function() {
         calculate();
        });
        function calculate(){

            var sPercent = parseInt($('#salePercent').val());
            var sPrice="";
            if(isNaN(uPrice) || isNaN(sPercent)){
                sPrice=" ";
               }else{
               sPrice = (uPrice*(1-(sPercent/100))).toFixed(2);
               }

            $('#salePrice').val(sPrice);
        }
```

What im looking to achieve is have "SalePrice" update based on the "UnitPrice" and "SalePrice" entered. With my current code above, this is not happening. I get no response from the cakephp form field "SalePrice". Is this even possible?

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lyum1/Lvm03ftc/) of how i would like it to work

Im really sorry if this is a novice question, I am new to javascript.

Kind regards

Comment: What is the exact issue you are having? Try to be precise. More precise questions lead to better, helpful answers.

Comment: Sorry. The issue I'm having is that the form field salePrice isnt updating. With my jsFiddle, salePrice updates upon input on the salePercent. However I'm not getting any response from my Cake form.

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations, it's already working!  I tested the jsfiddle, and everything works.